# mysqlslap running very slow on a specific computer

Tags: mysql, benchmark

I've recently discovered the tool mysqlslap and have run some simple tests with it. I currently have three test environments (2 Win 7, 1 Linux Ubuntu) where I can run these tests. However, running a no-op test on one of the Win 7 machines takes approximately 2 seconds. Running a similar query from for example MySQL Workbench takes no time, just as it should. This must have something to do with the configuration of my machine or MySQL (5.5).

Running a more heavy query takes longer time on the already slow machine, which is at least a little bit logical.

Does anybody have a clue why this happens?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out what the simple solution was. I needed to configure mysqlslap with --host and --user options for some reason yet unknown.